# how can i create a custom CellEncoder in kantan

Tags: scala, csv

i have a code that converts a list of case class into a csv string, i'm using kantan so when i tried to pass the encoder i have this error:

**`could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type kantan.csv.CellEncoder[Option[javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar]]`**

original date : `2020-08-13T21:52:27.000Z`

this is my code:

```
import kantan.csv._
import kantan.csv.ops._
import kantan.csv.java8._
import kantan.csv.CellEncoder
val itemsList :List[ItemData]  = getItems.getOrElse(Seq.empty[ItemData]).toList

implicit val itemEncoder: HeaderEncoder[ItemData] = HeaderEncoder.caseEncoder("absolutePath", "creationDate",
              "displayName", "fileName", "lastModified","lastModifier","owner","parentAbsolutePath","typeValue")(ItemData.unapply _)

val csvItems :String =itemsList.asCsv(rfc.withHeader)
```

the case class :

```
case class ItemData(absolutePath: Option[String] = None,
  creationDate: Option[javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar] = None,
  displayName: Option[String] = None,
  fileName: Option[String] = None,
  lastModified: Option[javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar] = None,
  lastModifier: Option[String] = None,
  owner: Option[String] = None,
  parentAbsolutePath: Option[String] = None,
  typeValue: Option[String] = None)
```

dependencies:

```
lazy val `kantan-csv`             = "com.nrinaudo"            %% "kantan.csv"               % Version.kantan
  lazy val `kantan-csv-commons`     = "com.nrinaudo"            %% "kantan.csv-commons"       % Version.kantan
  lazy val `kantan-csv-generic`     = "com.nrinaudo"            %% "kantan.csv-generic"       % Version.kantan
  lazy val `kantan-csv-java8`       = "com.nrinaudo"            %% "kantan.csv-java8"         % Version.kantan
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know much about `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`, so I'm not sure how you'd represent that as a string. This answer assumes it's done by calling `toString`, but change that to whatever is the correct way of doing so.

You need to provide a `CellEncoder[javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar]`. This is [documented](https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv/arbitrary_types_as_cells.html), and fairly straightforward:

```scala
implicit val xmlCalendarEncoder: CellEncoder[javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar] = CellEncoder.from(_.toString)
```

kantan.csv should be able to work out the rest for you.